# how to separate input string and populate on table view with how many times it repeated and passe the index to next

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I am very new to iOS and ObjectiveC. I searched everywhere but I didn't find required option and I was not able to understand.

```
UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @""
                                                                          message: @"Enter input text"
                                                                   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"Text";
    textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
}];
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                            {
                                NSArray * textfields = alertController.textFields;
                                UITextField * namefield = textfields[0];
                                inputstring=namefield.text;


                                for (int i = 0; i < [inputstring length]; i++) {
                                    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [inputstring characterAtIndex:i]]];
                                }
                                _firsttblview.delegate=self;
                                _firsttblview.dataSource=self;
                                [_firsttblview reloadData];
                            }]];


[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To display in the table view I used the following code.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    firstTableViewCell *cell = [_firsttblview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"firstTableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"firstTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    int count=0;
    cell.charlbl.text=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *singchstr=array[indexPath.row];
    for (int a=0; a<array.count; a++) {
        NSString *chrstrh=array[a];

        if ([chrstrh isEqualToString:singchstr]) {
            count ++;

        }
    }
    for (int b=0; b<indexPath.row; b++) {

        NSString *charststr=array[b];

        if ([singchstr isEqualToString:charststr]) {
            count=0;
            break;
        }
    }
    cell.countlbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
       return cell;

}
```

If I click on the index path I have to send the the all repeating index with this index path.

In the next table I have to delete one similar letter and I will go the back to then the letter in that index path should  delete.

Comment: @loesh,can please explain you requirement

Comment: hi satheesh,if you have 3 similar letters say a 3times and they are in different index when i click on the one index the in the next tabel it must show all A woth this indexs and id i delete one i come back tabelview must reload and taht index must delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In didselectrow:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

firstTableViewCell *cell = [_firsttblview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSMutableArray *indexpatharray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++) {

    NSString *charsring=array[i];
    if ([cell.charlbl.text isEqualToString:charsring]) {

        [indexpatharray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];

    }
}

 secondViewController  *viewcontroller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
viewcontroller.charStr = cell.charlbl.text;
viewcontroller.charArr = indexpatharray;
viewcontroller.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
 }

 -(void)passthearray:(NSMutableIndexSet *)set //meth
 {
[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:set];
[_firsttblview reloadData];
   }
   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return _charArr.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    firstTableViewCell *cell = [_secondtblview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"firstTableViewCell"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"firstTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.charlbl.text = _charStr;
cell.countlbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _charArr[indexPath.row]];

  return cell;

  }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    firstTableViewCell *cell = [_secondtblview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [_charArr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [indexes addIndex:[cell.countlbl.text integerValue]];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}

 }

 - (IBAction)submitbuttn:(id)sender {

[_delegate passthearray:indexes];

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
 @protocol reloadtabeldata <NSObject>

 -(void)passthearray:(NSMutableIndexSet *)set;
 @property(nonatomic,weak) id<reloadtabeldata> delegate;
```

Comment: I will check it and i will let you know.

Comment: i used all  you code but I am but app is getting crased with error erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:]: index set cannot be nil', method is her  -(void)passthearray:(NSMutableIndexSet *)set //meth
 {
[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:set];
[_firsttblview reloadData];
   }

Comment: @lokesh let me check

Comment: @lokesh add this in view did load  indexes = [NSMutableIndexSet new];